# Non blocking connect to loopback address (127.0.0.1 or localhost)

Tags: ios, macos, freebsd, ios-simulator

When I do a non blocking connect to the loopback address from the iOS Simulator (which probably uses the same TCP stack as the Mac and FreeBSD), I see that connect always succeeds, even when the server process isn't running.

I detect that connect succeeded by using select() with zero timeout. So, as long as select() returns 0, I assume that the connection is in progress, if it returns -1 I fail with an error and if it returns 1, the socket is ready for reading (as the server must have responded), and I begin reading after reporting that the connect succeeded.

This works well for all addresses except the loopback. On the loopback select() always returns 1, even when there is no server running. So, I begin reading, which fails and I handle it. But I should have detected this through select()!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was relying on select() to tell me if the connect was successful. Select only tells you if something changed on that fd. I should've actually called connect() again on the socket and verify that the if it fails, errno is either EINPROGRESS, ECONN or EALREADY. Except for ECONN, all the other values mean that we should retry; ECONN means it's already connected. Any other errno value means we failed to connect.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the error *before* that, right on `connect()`.
Before going to proceed with `select()`, check that `errno` is `EINPROGRESS` and not something else.  In *BSD, connections to a non-listening port on a `localhost` error out (or *may* error out) immediately.

I just ran a very simple test like this (headers skipped):

```
int
main(void)
{
    int fd;
    int r;
    struct sockaddr_in remote;
    struct hostent *he;

    he = gethostbyname("localhost");
    if (he == NULL)
            return -1;

    memcpy(&remote.sin_addr, he->h_addr, sizeof(remote.sin_addr));
    remote.sin_port = htons(9671);
    remote.sin_family = AF_INET;

    fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    r = connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, sizeof remote);
    if (r < 0) {
            perror("connect");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With nothing listening on port `9671`, I got:

- on Linux: `connect: Operation now in progress`
- on FreeBSD: `connect: Connection refused`

Of course, it is *always* a good idea to check the error codes of all syscalls (something the example above does not do for simplicity's sake - it's just an illustration, after all).

Comment: I'm actually getting EINPROGRESS from connect(). I'll check again and let you know.

Comment: I am sorry for assuming you did not check the result of `connect`.  By the way, are you selecting for reading, or for writing?  At least FreeBSD's `connect(2)` manpage seems to indicate that one should select for writing.

Comment: Yup, I did select for writing. Thanks for your effort!